# Batch command to open all files of a certain type in Notepad++

Tags: batch-file, filesystems

I have the following batch command to open files with `dtd` extension.

```
REM Open all the static content files
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\data\folder1\File1.dtd"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\data\folder1\File2.dtd"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\data\folder2\File1.dtd"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\data\folder2\File2.dtd"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\data\folder3\File1.dtd"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\data\folder3\File2.dtd"
```

How do I change this batch command to open all files with `dtd` extension under `"D:\data"` folder ?

I tried the below code but it does not work

```
REM Open all the static content files
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "D:\data\\*.dtd"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `FOR` command:

> `FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]`
>
> Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
>       statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
>       specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
>       assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
>       will just enumerate the directory tree.

In your case this should work:

```
FOR /R d:\data %a IN (*.dtd) DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%a"
```

Use `%%a` if you need to run this from a batch file

If you want to use multiple extensions you can separate those with a space

```
FOR /R d:\data %a IN (*.dtd *.xml *.xslt) DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%a"
```

Comment: Is it possible to include several fileendings in the IN (set) part at once?

Comment: @Kaiserludi yes, that turns out to be possible, I added that option in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to write the batch file in this way:

```
set command=C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
FOR /R d:\data %%a IN (*.dtd) DO %command% %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want files from previous session to be opened then add the `-nosession` parameter.
(here example for `dtd` extension in a `.bat` file)

```
for /R %%x in (*.dtd) do (
    start "" "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -nosession "%%x"
)
```