# Batch command to open files of the same name in Notepad++

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to open all files called "asdf.txt" in Notepad++, found in all subfolders from the directory that the batch file is located in.

The solution found here applies to file types but does not translate to exact file names:
[Batch command to open all files of a certain type in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525175/batch-command-to-open-all-files-of-a-certain-type-in-notepad)

Here is my attempt:

```
FOR /R %%a IN (asdf.txt) DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%%a"
```

This results in Notepad++ stating that asdf.txt doesn't exist and would I like to create it. It continues to ask me for every subfolder that exists (which can be hundreds of times). If I say yes, then it creates the file asdf.txt in every subfolder. If I keep pressing yes/no, then it eventually does open the existing files. What I want, however, is to open all existing files with exactly the same name and not create new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your filename doesn't contain any wildcard, so it's taken as a string, not a file mask.
Either add a wildcard:

```
 FOR /R %%a IN ("asdf.txt?") DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%%a"
```

or use:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /s /b /a-d "asdf.txt"') DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%%a"
```

Comment: Thank you. The second solution worked great. The first solution only opened one asdf.txt file (and then would open a second one after notepad++ was closed and opened again).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `Where` command:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where/R <srcDir> asdf.txt') Do @Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%%A"
```

Change `<srcDir>` to your specific source directory, *(use a dot for the current directory). You can of course remove the `Start ""` command if it doesn't suit your specific requirements*